# set labels for Xaxis in MPandroid Chart (Bar Chart)

Tags: android, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I have been trying to figure out and have read many post. but i am unable to set labels to xaxis in Bar Chart of MPAndroid. currently it is showing the position of the bar.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to answer without your work samples , try this, it may help you

```
// Plotting Data
ArrayList<BarEntry> XValues = new ArrayList<>();
BarEntry v1e1 = new BarEntry(110.000f, 0);  
valueSet1.add(v1e1);
// Setting X label this way
BarDataSet set = new BarDataSet(XValues, "Age Distribution");
```

Comment: Hi @Vinod Kumar , can you please answer my bounty question regarding xAxis labels https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55325511/mpandroid-chart-not-displaying-any-labels-for-xaxis-what-is-missing?noredirect=1#comment97407907_55325511

Answer (score 0):

- Step 1 : Initialize x axis like this =  in global =  ArrayList xaxis0
  Initialize  xaxis0 = new ArrayList<>();
- Step 2 : After that if you have arraylist strings of data.Then start loop 
  add all strings into the x axis values like below code

  ```
   for (int i = 0; i < xdata.size(); i++)
   {                       

         * xaxis0.add(i, xdata.get(i).get("date"));

         int data222 = Integer.parseInt(str);

         BarEntry v1e11 = new BarEntry(data222, i);

    }


    BarDataSet barDataSet1 = new BarDataSet(valueSet1, "Top 5 deals");

    barDataSet1.setColors(whitecolors);

    barDataSet1.setHighLightColor(Color.GREEN);

    barDataSet1.setBarSpacePercent(60f);

    barDataSet1.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);

    dataSets = new ArrayList<>();

    dataSets.add(barDataSet1);

   *BarData data11 = new BarData(xaxis0, dataSets);

    data11.setValueFormatter(new LargeValueFormatter());

    data11.setGroupSpace(100f);

    holder.chart.setData(data11);
  ```
- That's its ...